# Populating Reactive Form from Clicking on an Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out how to populate a reactive form using the data from an angular material table. I can do it in a template driven table using:

```
populateForm(rd: Shift) {
    this.shiftsService.formData = Object.assign({}, rd)
  }
```

but I'm not being able to implement the same knowledge to populate a reactive form.

Here's a working example:
https://angular-ivy-uwuzdg.stackblitz.io

This is what the table looks like:

```
<mat-card>
  <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <mat-form-field fxFlex="30%">
          <mat-label>Search Shift</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placerholder="filter">
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="start">  <!--grouping mechanism -->
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Start</th> <!--structural directive-->
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="populateForm(element)">{{ element.start | date }}</td>
      </ng-container>
```

this is the table.ts

```
export class ShiftsListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = ['start', 'end', 'category', 'location', 'money', 'button'] // for the dataTable, names have to match "matcolumndef" on view
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Shift>();

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(public shiftsService: ShiftsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllShifts();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  doFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  // hideValues () {
  //   this.dataSource.filteredData()
  // }


  populateForm(rd: Shift) {
    console.log("mr. populate")
    this.shiftsService.formData = Object.assign({}, rd)
  }

  public getAllShifts() {
    let resp = this.shiftsService.getShifts();
    console.log(resp)
    resp.then(shifts => this.dataSource.data = shifts as Shift[]);
  }

  onDelete(id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.shiftsService.deleteShiftDetail(id)
        .subscribe(
          res => {
          this.shiftsService.getShifts()
            .then(shifts => this.dataSource.data = shifts as Shift[]);
         },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
    }
  }
}
```

this is the form

```
<form
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayoutAlign="center center"
  fxLayoutGap="10px"
  [formGroup]="shiftsForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
  >
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="pickerStart" placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="dateStart"
    [disabled]="disabled">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #pickerStart [showSpinners]="showSpinners"
      [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond" >
    </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="pickerEnd" placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="dateEnd"
    [disabled]="disabled">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerEnd"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #pickerEnd [showSpinners]="showSpinners"
      [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond">
    </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

this is the form.ts

```
export class ShiftsFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public disabled = false;
  public showSpinners = true;
  public stepHour = 1;
  public stepMinute = 1;
  public stepSecond = 1;

  public options = [
    { value: true, label: 'True' },
    { value: false, label: 'False' }
  ];

  public listColors = ['primary', 'accent', 'warn'];

  public stepHours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  public stepMinutes = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
  public stepSeconds = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

  shiftsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private shiftsService: ShiftsService) { }


   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.shiftsForm = new FormGroup ({
       category: new FormControl(""),
       location: new FormControl(""),
       money: new FormControl(""),
       dateStart : new FormControl(new Date("")),
       dateEnd : new FormControl(new Date(""))
     });

     console.log(this.shiftsService.getShifts());
   }

   onSubmit() {
     console.log(this.shiftsForm)
     this.shiftsService.postShiftDetail({
       start: this.shiftsForm.value.dateStart,
       end: this.shiftsForm.value.dateEnd,
       money: this.shiftsForm.value.money,
       categoryId: this.shiftsForm.value.category,
       locationId: this.shiftsForm.value.location,
    }).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("Yay")
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });;
   }
}
```

this is the service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShiftsService {
  formData: Shift;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Shift>();
  // categoryFormData: Category;

  // readonly rootURL = 'https://cappuccinobudget.azurewebsites.net/api';
  readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:5001/api';

  private fbSubs: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postShiftDetail(formData) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    }
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/shifts', formData, httpOptions)

  }

  putShiftDetail() {
    return this.http.put(
      this.rootURL + '/shifts/' + this.formData.id,
      this.formData)
  }

  deleteShiftDetail(id) {
    return this.http.delete(
      this.rootURL + '/shifts/' + id,
    )
  }

  public getShifts() {
    return this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/shifts').toPromise()
    .then(shifts => this.dataSource.data = shifts as Shift[]);
  }
```

Comment: You’ll need a reference to the formGroup (shiftsForm?) and then call a patchValue(rd) on it? So this.shiftsForm.patchValue(rd)?

Comment: Ok I did some research and I understand how to use patchValue now. But I'm still struggling to pass the table data into it. :/

Comment: The data you pass in has to match the keys of the formcontrols..